# Apollo GraphQL, consume all the operations via web sockets

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am looking for informations about **using web sockets for all the graphql operations in apollo** (query, mutations, etc.).

1. Is this possible?
2. Does Apollo have a `link` for this? I have found enough information about subscriptions, but not very lucky for all the others.
3. What are the main concerns about this strategy?